# What does map.position.set() do in this Autodesk Viewer GeoThree extension?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm working with the Autodesk Viewer and trying to understand the following code for a custom extension  [Geo-three-ext](https://github.com/wallabyway/geo-three-ext)

```js
class GeoThreeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  load() {
    // etc...
    const position = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().metadata.georeference.positionLL84;
    var map = new Geo.MapView(Geo.MapView.PLANAR, provider);
    map.position.set(position) //output example : (-71.0603, 42.3583, 0);
    viewers[0].overlays.addScene("map");
    viewers[0].overlays.addMesh(map, "map");
    map.updateMatrixWorld(false);
    // etc...
  }
}
```

Specifically, I'm not sure what the map.position.set() call does. The documentation for the Autodesk Viewer and the Three.js library it uses doesn't seem to provide a clear explanation.

Based on my understanding, the position variable is set to the geographic location of the file being viewed, and map is a new instance of the Geo.MapView class that represents a map overlay. But what exactly is happening when we call map.position.set(-71.0603, 42.3583, 0)? Is this setting the position of the map relative to the file's georeferenced origin?

When I try in the console of the brower this code :

```js
NOP_VIEWER.loadExtension('Autodesk.Geolocation').then((e) => { temp1 = e});
temp1.activate()
```

I've this result
Any insights or clarifications would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: May i know the design file format?

Answer (score 0):

The map.position.set() will place the Revit model, which is usually at origin (0,0,0), at a position on the Earth, based on WGS84 coordinates.

You can find out more information here:
[Maps into Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68122676/maps-into-forge-viewer/68310081?noredirect=1#comment121318690_68310081)

and in the update section in the original blog post here:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/add-mapbox-google-maps-forge-viewer